# Pod spec lint with CoreML

Tags: cocoapods, coreml

I get this message when I try to update my pod with `pod spec lint` which contains a CoreML class called ForceTouch. Please help me solve this issue and get my pod updated...[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. [Edit] your question and replace the picture with the actual text, copied and pasted into your question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are much harder to read.

Comment: The pictures is almost secondary. I just am having issues getting a .coreml class in my pod.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the pod doesn't include the source file that is automatically generated by Xcode.

One easy workaround: copy-paste that automatically generated file into real Swift file and add it to your project. (And turn off automatic Core ML code generation in the project settings screen.)

Comment: That got rid of some errors, however when I run `pod spec lint` now, I still get the bottom two errors from above. The compiler doesn't seem to recognizer the `ForceTouch` or `ForceTouchInput` even when its not in an autogenerated class.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: No idea, I have only little experience with CocoaPods. I'm also not sure what the current error message is.